# Find the remainder R (x) if it holds that:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

\begin{align*}                                                               
  P(x) &= q(x)(x^2+x+1)+x+1  \\                                              
  P(x) &= Q(x)(x^2-x+1)+x-1  \\                                             
P(x) &= M(x)(x^4+x^2+1)+ R(x)                                              
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algebraic useful identity$$x^4+x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-x^2=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+1+x)(x^2+1-x)$$
to give remainder $(x+1)$ when divided by $(x^2+x+1)$ and remainder $(x-1)$ when divided by $(x^2-x+1)$ polynomial must be like
$$P(x)=\left(x^2+x+1\right) \left[\left(x^2-x+1\right) Q(x)+x-1\right]+x+1$$
$$P(x)=Q(x)(x^4+x^2+1)+[(x^2+x+1)(x-1)+(x+1)]$$
$$P(x)=\left(x^4+x^2+1\right) Q(x)+x^3+x$$
$$R(x)=x^3+x$$

Comment: I don't understand your procedure. Why is $P(x)$ and $q(x)$ equal?

Comment: I have added some detail @ArnoldFernández